# Graph API: Post to a group feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, post

I have programmed a working PHP script which was posting news to a feed of a group. But somehow it doesn't work anymore, not even if I try to do it with the [Graph API itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXneg.png):

[image]

But why? This is how I did it many times before sucessfully... Now it isn't working anymore and I get this error msg... Can anybody tell me why and how I can fix it?

I already changed my access token -> Same problem
I already looked up if the group ID has changed -> Still the same

This is my PHP Code:

```
$group_url  = "https://graph.facebook.com/825764260964348/feed";
$data['link'] = $this->product[1];
$data['picture'] = $this->product[2];
$data['message'] = str_replace("%%short_url%%", $this->product[1], $message);
$data['access_token'] = "IAMAPLACEHOLDER";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $group_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec($ch)
```

I would bet this PHP code is correct cause it was working...
Kind regards and Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes

> Testing of our more robust process starts today and the new process
>   should resume in a few weeks, but **apps currently accessing Events and
>   Groups APIs will lose access today**.

At the moment, there is no access to groups with the API.

Comment: Thank you... thats the reason tho.. And it will lose access for pages as well?

Comment: open the link, a lot of stuff got removed, but pages are not affected that much.

Comment: Do you know why tho?

Comment: that information should be in the link too. another keyword: cambridge analytica.

Comment: @luschn that means that at this moment there is no way to publish to facebook groups?

Comment: yes. in addition, you should read the breaking changes: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#groups-4-4